# Dynamically loading UserControl in WPF Assembly missing resources

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-assembly, mef

I have a `WPF` application with a `TabControl` where the `TabItems` are loaded dynamically during runtime. It's not known which tabs will be loaded when the application starts. This is why I use the following code to add the .dll's to the Assembly:

```
// Load the UserControl to the Assembly
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(ProjectPath + "\\ControlLibrary.dll");

// Resolve the missing files from the loaded UserControl
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (obj, arg) =>
{
    // Get full name of missing dll
    var name = $"{new AssemblyName(arg.Name).Name}.dll";

    if (arg.RequestingAssembly != null && arg.RequestingAssembly.Location != null)
    {
        string tmp = Path.GetDirectoryName(arg.RequestingAssembly.Location);
        var referenceFiles = Directory.GetFiles(tmp, "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        // Attempt to find missing file in project directory
        var assemblyFile = referenceFiles.Where(x => x.EndsWith(name)).FirstOrDefault();
        // Load missing reference if found
        if (assemblyFile != null)
        {
            return Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyFile);
        }

    }
    throw new Exception($"'{name}' Not found");
};
```

This works just fine when I only load one tab.

The problem is that all the tabs are `UserControls` and all they are all called ControlLibrary.dll. The contents of these `UserControls` differ, so one instance may have custom controls that the other doesn't. When I load 2 tabs and switch between these tabs, I get `IOExceptions` telling me that some custom controls are not found. These controls only exist in one instance of the `ControlLibrary.dll` so my guess is that the resources are only loaded for the first instance of the `ControlLibrary`.

In the code sample above the only files that are being resolved are `.dll` files but the event handler is also called where the `arg.Name` contains `ControlLibrary.resources`. As this isn't a `.dll` file no further action is taken. There also isn't a file with the name `ControlLibrary.resources` in the output directory so I'm unsure how this has to be loaded.

I went down the [MEF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/) rabbithole to load the files but this eventually ended up in getting `ChangeRejectedExceptions` when I tried to load the second `ControlLibrary.dll`. For this I used the code below:

```
// Load the ControlLibrary assembly
var controlLibraryAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);

// Create a catalog for the ControlLibrary assembly
var controlLibraryCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(controlLibraryAssembly);

// Add the ControlLibrary catalog to the AggregateCatalog
((AggregateCatalog)container.Catalog).Catalogs.Add(controlLibraryCatalog);

// Compose the new parts
container.ComposeParts(this); // This throws a ChangeRejectionException.
```